# Convergence in distribution of $\frac{1}{n}max(X_n,Y_n)$, where $X_n\text{ }U(-n-5,4n-5)$, $Y_n\text{ }Poiss(10n)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Convergence in distribution of $\frac{1}{n}max(X_n,Y_n)$, where $X_n\text{ is }U(-n-5,4n-5)$, $Y_n\text{ is }Poiss(10n)$. My idea is to look how $X_n, Y_n$ behave as n tends to infinity, so my first observation is that probability of $X_n$ being infinity is positive as n tends to infinity, however poisson distribution "converges to zero" as n tends to infinity. So I think the only important factor in maximum is the uniform variable, but I might be wrong. Can anyone relate?

The PDF of $\frac{1}{n}max{(X_n,Y_n)}$ is $$\frac{tn+n+5}{5n}e^{-10n}\sum_{k=0}^{\floor{tn}}\frac{10n^{k}}{k!}$$, so we are up to calculating the limit of it when n tends to infinity...  $$\text{After a while I think this limit is zero.}$$

Comment: Excellent. Have you tried computing the cdf of $1/n \max(X_n, Y_n)$ ?

Comment: I would do that, had I known the CDF of poisson distribution.

Comment: Well you could just look it up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Is the calculation correct? I do not think I can do the cancelation of this sum with $e^{-10n}$

Comment: You need an indicator function of the set $tn \in [-n-5, 4n-5]$. In the sum it should be $(10n)^k$.

Comment: Hint: $$\tfrac1n\max\{X_n,Y_n\}\stackrel d\to 10$$